# EU/Schengen: Is a visa required if you have work permit?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, indian-citizens, sweden, permits

I am a non-EU citizen (with Indian passport) travelling to Sweden on a work permit. The embassy told me that all I need to carry are the passport and the work/residence permit card. Is that it? I mean, my passport has nothing affixed to it. Isn't a visa required if you have a work permit?

On a related note:
Can I travel to other countries in the EU/Schengen zone with a work permit from one of them? If yes, is there a restriction on the number of days?

Comment: it's awesome how people trust travel.SE more than an embassy :-)

Comment: Celebrate the fact that you are part of such a community :)

Comment: @Prometheus: please put where are traveling from in this question and the question about med. insurance.

Comment: Travelling from India and crossing the Schengen zone in Helsinki.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Official requirements for a non-EU citizen to **enter Schengen zone** ([source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schengen_Area#Entry_conditions_for_third-country_nationals)):

> - He/she is in possession of a valid [**travel document**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travel_document) or documents authorising them to cross the border; the acceptance of
>     travel documents for this purpose remains within the domain of the
>     member states;
> - The travel document must be valid for at least 3 months after the intended date of departure from the Schengen Area (although in a
>     justified case of emergency this obligation may be waived) and must
>     have been issued within the previous 10 years
> - The traveller either possesses a valid visa (if required) **or a valid residence permit**;
> - The traveller can justify the purpose and conditions of the intended stay and has sufficient means of subsistence, both for the duration of
>     the intended stay and for the return to his or her country of origin
>     or transit to a third country into which the traveller is certain to
>     be admitted, or is in a position to acquire such means lawfully;
> - The Schengen Information System does not contain an alert for refusal of entry concerning the traveller, and
> - The traveller is not considered to be a threat to public policy, internal security, public health or the international relations of any
>     of the Schengen states.

However, once you're **inside of Schengen zone**:

> *What is the legal rights of foreigners within the Schengen area?*
>
> The
>   Schengen Agreement permits individuals who are staying legally within
>   the Schengen territory to travel about inside the territory without
>   border checks. This does not only apply to the citizens of these
>   countries but also to foreigners. Thus, **foreigners with a valid
>   residence permit in a Schengen State and carrying valid documents can
>   travel within the territory and do not need any special permission to
>   do so.**

Note, that even though residency card is generally accepted as photo ID, it is **not** a travel document, and won't be accepted by various airlines.

On the other hand non-Schengen EU countries (for example UK) may require additional visa.